# Is sexism illegal in Germany?

Tags: germany, discrimination

In Germany, is sexism illegal?

Comment: Wait what? I'm confused - would racism be illegal as well? Also, how does men differ from women in this sense? If sexism against women is illegal, it would likely be illegal against men. Speaking of which, in Canada, there are crimes that go along the general lines of hate, which if I remember correctly, you can be charged for *promoting hate progaganda*. Basically, promoting hatred towards a specific group. There are exceptions, such as when the information is factually correct, but I doubt that is the case here.

Comment: @Zizouz212 I don't know if this case is illegal in Germany. Therfor I asked. We have §130 in the StGB about 'rabble-rousing'. But I don't know if it fits there. So, in general, I would just like to know if sexism (at all) is illegal in Germany :-)

Comment: So I assume that you know that sexism/racism is illegal. Perhaps finding the applicable law could be useful in determining this?

Comment: @Zizouz212 No, I don't know if sexism is allowed in Germany. I don't know if §130 in the StGB cover sexism too. The talk is just about national, religious, ethnical and racial discrimination. There is no talk about gender there. But since I'm not a lawyer, I would just like to know, if the paragraph also cover sexism or if there is any law in Germany that cover it. Racism is illegal according to this law, but nothing is written about gender discrimination there :-)

Comment: It should also be noted that in many jurisdictions if not most, speech that would be prohibited in many contexts is permissible in comedy, satire, or parody.

Comment: Define *sexism.*

Comment: I think this should be closed as "too broad". "Sexism" can mean different things to different people. Without a proper definition, there is no meaningful answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot speak for Germany specifically but based on the jurisdictions I know sexism (or racism, ageism etc.) is not illegal.

Discrimination based on sex is illegal. Incitement to violence (aka hate speech) is illegal. Having and expressing sexist views is not illegal; however, it is reprehensible and, in relation to measurable differences in the physiology or performance of male and female brains, scientifically inaccurate.

Comment: http://www.livestrong.com/article/246036-how-much-more-muscle-mass-does-a-male-have-than-a-female/ http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8477683 http://healthyliving.azcentral.com/much-muscle-mass-male-female-1709.html

Answer (score 5):

No, sexism is not illegal in Germany.

Discrimination based on sexism is illegal in, for example, employment, business, or housing.

Sexist speech itself is not illegal, but the usual restrictions apply - insulting people is not protected speech in Germany, see [StGB §185-187](http://gangway.de/straftaten-gegen-die-ehre-beleidigung-ueble-nachrede-verleumdung-%C2%A7%C2%A7-185-187-stgb/) (German text).

Furthermore, employers have a duty to protect their employees from discrimination and bullying by their peers, so not doing anything when an employee reports sexism can also be fined.

Most of this is covered under the [General Act on Equal Treatment](http://www.antidiskriminierungsstelle.de/EN/TheAct/theAct_node.html), which covers discrimination based on

> the grounds of race or ethnic origin, gender, religion or belief, disability, age or sexual orientation